# Mongoose: atomic FindOne-Or-Insert(), do not update existing instance if found

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, atomic

In Mongoose, I am seeking to perform atomically a way to `Model.FindOne-Or-Insert()`, similar functionality and signature as currently available [`Model.FindOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) except if an instance exists (i.e. matches `filter`) then **do not update using provided `object`** but return instance found as is, and if not exists (i.e. no match with `filter`) then insert `object` and return new instance.

I could not find a way using [`Model.FindOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) not to perform an update to an existing instance by trying out variances to its `options` and not providing fields to `object` that preferred not to update if instance exists.

So, my current **non-atomic** workaround is [`Model.FindOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) and if not found then perform [`Document.save()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save).

```
const Foo = DB.model('foo', FooSchema)

async function findOneAndUpdateFoo(jsonFoo, next) {

  const filter = {
    deletedAt: null
  }
  if (jsonFoo.dsAccountId) {
    filter.dsAccountId = jsonFoo.dsAccountId
  }
  if (jsonIntegration.dsUserId) {
    filter.dsUserId = jsonIntegration.dsUserId
  }
  if (jsonFoo.providerId) {
    filter.providerId = jsonFoo.providerId
  }

  const fooDoc = {
    name: jsonFoo.name,
    dsAccountId: jsonFoo.dsAccountId,
    dsUserId: jsonFoo.dsUserId,
    providerId: jsonFoo.providerId,
    providerName: jsonFoo.providerName,

    // Most of these fields could be empty
    accessToken: jsonFoo.accessToken,
    refreshToken: jsonFoo.refreshToken,
    scope: jsonFoo.scope,
    tokenType: jsonFoo.tokenType,
    expiresAt: jsonFoo.expiresAt
  }

  return await Foo.findOneAndUpdate(
    filter, // find a document with that filter
    fooDoc, // document to insert when nothing was found
    { upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true } // options
  )
    .catch(next)
}
```

Suggestions? Thank you

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thank you for your prompt reply. I had updated my question show code using Model.FindOneAndUpdate(). I am checking out your suggestion now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert) in your update parameter so that it will only apply in the insert case; with the update becoming a no-op in the case where the document already exists:

```
return await Foo.findOneAndUpdate(
  filter,                 // find a document with that filter
  {$setOnInsert: fooDoc}, // document to insert when nothing was found
  { upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true }
)
```

Note that you should also create a unique index over the fields included in your `filter` and then handle the possibility of a duplicate error. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295648/mongoose-duplicate-key-error-with-upsert) for the details why.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert) did the trick!

Comment: @JohnnyHK is upsert: true required?

Comment: Also in my case index is the objectId.