# inserting duplicate with update and upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using mongoose and used `updateOne` with `upset=true`,but on same id it inserting duplicate document.

`Company.updateOne({ 'vendorId': company_id}, { $set: query }, { upsert: true })`

but for the same vendor, it inserting multiple documents.

Please help me.

Comment: Could your provide yourr `Company` schema, and value of `company_id` ?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295648/mongoose-duplicate-key-error-with-upsert